# css: inside body class, simple text gets shadow but the links get it too?

Tags: html, css

in my css i have a problem:

```
body.transparent {background-color: transparent;color:#ffffff;text-shadow: 0 -1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, -1px 0 #000;}
```

The text-shadow was supposed to affect only simple, non-formated text. But it not just affects that text, but also the links.

How do i prevent the links on this body class from getting a shadow? (be aware that it cannot affect other body classes..)

Comment: Which browsers are you testing this in? What does your affected html look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body.transparent a {text-shadow: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a style for the included a tag, or at least for all children of transparent, overriding the default.

by example:

```
.transparent * {background-color: none;color:#000000;text-shadow: none;}
```